# Different material on back and frontside of extruded shape

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to apply different material on front and back sides of extruded shape, but cannot figure out where to put `side: THREE.FrontSide` and `side: THREE.BackSide`. Where they should be putted?

My relevant code part is:

```
var materialFront = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ ambient: 0xffffff, map: frontTexture });

var materialSide = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xE68A00, ambient: 0xffffff});

var extrusionSettings = {
          amount: 10,
          bevelEnabled: false,
          bevelThickness: 0.2,
          bevelSize: 0.2,
          bevelSegments: 8,
          material: 0,
          extrudeMaterial: 1
};

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shapes, extrusionSettings);

var materials = [materialFront, materialSide];

var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

---

UPDATE:
According to WestLangley's comment I succeeded in adding the different texture to backfaces:

```
// ...
var materials = [materialFront, materialSide, materialBack];
// ...
for ( var face in mesh.geometry.faces ) {
if (mesh.geometry.faces[ face ].normal.z == 1) mesh.geometry.faces[ face ].materialIndex = 2;
}
```

Comment: `THREE.FrontSide` refers to the front side of a `face`, not the front side of a `mesh` or `shape`. What is not working, exactly?

Comment: Using the above code, when I look the mesh from backside, the `materialFront` is also there. I'd want to add a different material on the backside of the mesh, like the dice cube in http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Textures.html.

Comment: In the three.js source there is "material: <int> // material index for front and back faces". This seems to mean that the front and back faces cannot have different materials, because they have only one index. This is the core of the problem. I should be able to use one index for back and one index for front.

Comment: It is what it is. You have to follow the instructions in my answer and change the material index for all faces that are on the back side of your geometry.

Comment: How can I know, which faces are backside?

Comment: And as a side note: Is there not extrusion settings similar to this: `frontMaterial`, `backMaterial`, `extrudeMaterial`?

Comment: The face normals for faces on the back of the geometry should all point in the same direction. You could also identify the back faces by their z-coordinate, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick. If you update your answer by the detailed code, I'll accept it. I updated already my question by the working code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you create your mesh geometry, and *before the first call* to `render()`, you have to change the `materialIndex` to 2 for the back faces. Then, add a third material in your material array.

You can identify the back faces by their face normals. Face normals for faces on the back of the geometry should all point in the same direction.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I checked f3() and f4(), but they didn't gave an answer to how "to set the materialIndex to 2 for the back faces". Could you clarify this?

Comment: OK. If you could help me on this, I'd be very happy. So far all my attempts has failed.

Comment: Thanks for this! I updated my question with the desired code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16484835/1691517. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
var materialFront = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ ambient: 0xffffff, map: frontTexture, side: THREE.FrontSide });
var materialSide = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xE68A00, ambient: 0xffffff, side: THREE.BackSide });
```

even though you should probably lower your ambient contribution and give a `color` to the FrontSide material.

Then:

```
var materials = [materialFront, materialSide];
scene.add( THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, materials ));
```

Comment: In my code `materialSide` is attached to extrusionSettings.extrudeMaterial. So I cannot use it for backSide. I cannot see how your proposal could work.