# How can I differently color the front and back of a shape?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I apply different colors to the front and back sides of a shape? My attempt:

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape( pts );
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x66CC00, wireframe: false } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 );
scene.add( mesh );
```

Comment: do you mean different color of a face or different color on one side, and different on other?. You might need to use face material instead on lambert

Comment: i need like this http://jsfiddle.net/mdAb7/11/ but here used "PlaneGeometry" but my code have a  "ExtrudeGeometry".

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484835/different-material-on-back-and-frontside-of-extruded-shape

Comment: Already i tried but  it's not work.

Comment: Fixed grammar; tightened wording; improved code format.

Comment: You neglected to tell us what you get from your code.  I see only one colour in this; where is the other colour applied?

Comment: I don't think its possible to have different colors on extrude shape. Can you post a working example of what you have till now?