# Three.js: ExtrudeGeometry: Problems setting different material for front and back side

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating an ExtrudeGeometry of a hexagon shape and trying to set a different material for the front side and back side, as it is stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484835).

```
let shape = new THREE.Shape();
/*...*/

let geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
    steps: 2,
    amount: 0.05,
    bevelEnabled: false,
    material: 0,                //frontMaterial = green
    extrudeMaterial: 1          //sideMaterial  = gray
});

//Searching for the back side and setting the marialIndex accordingly
for (let face of geometry.faces) {
    if (face.normal.z == 1) {
        face.materialIndex = 2; //backMaterial  = red
    }
}

let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial([frontMaterial, sideMaterial, backMaterial]));
```

The problem now is, that this method (iterating over the faces and looking for those with `normal.z == 1`) does not work correctly with a `extrudeGeometry.amount = 0.05`. A value of `0.1` works fine.

[image: Example of wrong materials]

[See this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhbu2e01/2/)

Is there another method for setting a different material for front and back side or am I doing it just wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tip: `AmbientLight` should not be as bright as you set it in your fiddle. Set the intensity to 0.2 and add, for example, a `DirectionalLight` to the scene -- or a `PointLight` to the camera. Or just use `MeshBasicMaterial`, which does not respond to lights.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @WestLangley. In my real app I have an abientLight of 0.1, a directionalLight of 0.5 and a pointLight of 0.8, but I'm really no expert in lightning ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to rounding. Do this, instead

```
if ( face.normal.z < - 0.99999 ) { // instead of == - 1

    face.materialIndex = 2;

}
```

Also, the back face normal is in theory (0, 0, - 1 ).

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xhbu2e01/3/

three.js r.84

Comment: Can be so logical and easy. Thank you!